# Highly dispair execution times when changing comparision value on query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a problem with execution times on a query that is baffling me.
I know a few ways to solve the problem and get better and acceptable execution times but still don't have a clue on WHY the problem occurs.

### Sample Tables

We have TWO tables, related by a foreign key.

**Table1**

```
| Id | IdTable2 |
|:--:|:--------:|
|  1 |     4    |
|  2 |     7    |
|  3 |     8    |
|  4 |     6    |
|  5 |     4    |
|  6 |     1    |
|  7 |     1    |
|  8 |     6    |
|  9 |     7    |
| 10 |     1    |
```

**Table2**

```
| Id | ValueField |
|:--:|:----------:|
|  1 |      0     |
|  2 |      0     |
|  3 |      0     |
|  4 |      1     |
|  5 |      0     |
|  6 |      1     |
|  7 |      0     |
```

### Query

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE IdTable2 IN (SELECT Id FROM Table2 WHERE ValueField = ?);
```

Where `?` can be `0` or `1`

### Real Data Count

The above tables are just a sample to simplify, but the real row counts of this tables is as follows:

- Table1: **60420** rows
- Table2: **62** rows
- Table2 with ValueField `0`: **51** rows
- Table2 with ValueField `1`: **11** rows
- Table1 with IdTable2 with ValueField `0`: **599** rows
- Table1 with IdTable2 with ValueField `1`: **59821** rows

### The Issue

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE IdTable2 IN (SELECT Id FROM Table2 WHERE ValueField = 0);
-- Execution time LOW/INSTANT
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE IdTable2 IN (SELECT Id FROM Table2 WHERE ValueField = 1);
-- Execution time HIGH
```

Well, first of all I think that the subquery was the struggle, but if the subquery is the problem, different values would not execute in so dispair times, so I guess  that probably the amount of data retrieved was the problem, so I try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE IdTable2 IN (1,2,3,5,7); -- Equivalent of ValueField 0
-- Execution time LOW/INSTANT
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE IdTable2 IN (4,6); -- Equivalent of ValueField 1
-- Execution time LOW/INSTANT
```

Well... the data retrieved isn't it either, let's try something else:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE IdTable2 IN (SELECT Id FROM Table2 WHERE ValueField = 0);
-- Execution time LOW/INSTANT
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE IdTable2 NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM Table2 WHERE ValueField = 0);
-- Execution time LOW/INSTANT
```

What happen if I reverse it?

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE IdTable2 NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM Table2 WHERE ValueField = 1);
-- Execution time LOW/INSTANT
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE IdTable2 IN (SELECT Id FROM Table2 WHERE ValueField = 0);
-- Execution time LOW/INSTANT
```

Hummm.... that's pretty much tells me that the problem isn't on subquery and either on the data, but Why comparision with `ValueField = 1` AND using `IN` is causing the problem and none of the alternatives can replicate the HIGH execution times?

### Execution Plans

For SQL IN ValueField `1`:

```
SELECT * FROM Incidencias WHERE EstadoWorkflow in (SELECT IdEstadoWorkflow FROM EstadosWorkflows WHERE Final = 1);
```

http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=19036217708532467879

For SQL IN ValueField `0`:

```
SELECT * FROM Incidencias WHERE EstadoWorkflow in (SELECT IdEstadoWorkflow FROM EstadosWorkflows WHERE Final = 0);
```

http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=49593927895920014301

For SQL NOT IN ValueField `0`:

```
SELECT * FROM Incidencias WHERE EstadoWorkflow not in (SELECT IdEstadoWorkflow FROM EstadosWorkflows WHERE Final = 0);
```

http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=03901091628843565847

For SQL NOT IN ValueField `1`:

```
SELECT * FROM Incidencias WHERE EstadoWorkflow not in (SELECT IdEstadoWorkflow FROM EstadosWorkflows WHERE Final = 1);
```

http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=69996775965382534356

The queries are just the same I post in the example but with other names, this is the dictionary of equivalences of sample query vs real query.

- **Table1**: Incidencias
- **Table2**: EstadosWorkflows
- **IdTable2**: EstadoWorkflow
- **Table2.Id**: IdEstadoWorkflow
- **ValueField**: Final

And in reverse for better reading:

- **Incidencias**: Table1
- **EstadosWorkflows**: Table2
- **EstadoWorkflow**: IdTable2
- **IdEstadoWorkflow**: Table2.Id
- **Final**: ValueField

### Real Production Queries

This queries with the query plans show the same problem but with additional costly operations (like the huge exists and joins) and the problem get worse.
I really hope I wasn't misleading you with the simplified examples.

**Query `IN` with value `0`**

```
SELECT distinct top 15 this_.IdIncidencia as y0_, this_.Fecha as y1_ 
FROM Incidencias this_ inner join Usuarios usuario1_ on this_.Usuario=usuario1_.IdUsuario inner join Usuarios_Perfiles perfiles5_ on usuario1_.IdUsuario=perfiles5_.Usuario and (perfiles5_.perfil in (select perfiles.idperfil from perfiles where perfiles.borrado = 0)) inner join Perfiles prf2_ on perfiles5_.Perfil=prf2_.IdPerfil 
WHERE 
this_.Instancia = 4 and 
this_.EstadoWorkflow in (SELECT this_0_.IdEstadoWorkflow as y0_ FROM EstadosWorkflows this_0_ WHERE this_0_.Final = 0) and 
exists (SELECT this_0_.IdPerfilPermiso as y0_ FROM Perfiles_Permisos this_0_ inner join Permisos prm1_ on this_0_.Permiso=prm1_.IdPermiso WHERE this_0_.IdPerfilPermiso in (206558, 206559, 209393, 209394) and (this_0_.PerfilAutorizado = prf2_.IdPerfil and this_0_.TipologiaAutorizada = this_.Tipologia and prm1_.Controlador = 'Incidencias' and prm1_.Accion = 'Index')) 
ORDER BY this_.Fecha desc
```

Execution time: **266ms**.
Execution plan: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=36115325682943356233

**Query `IN` with value `1`**

```
SELECT distinct top 15 this_.IdIncidencia as y0_, this_.Fecha as y1_ 
FROM Incidencias this_ inner join Usuarios usuario1_ on this_.Usuario=usuario1_.IdUsuario inner join Usuarios_Perfiles perfiles5_ on usuario1_.IdUsuario=perfiles5_.Usuario and (perfiles5_.perfil in (select perfiles.idperfil from perfiles where perfiles.borrado = 0)) inner join Perfiles prf2_ on perfiles5_.Perfil=prf2_.IdPerfil 
WHERE 
this_.Instancia = 4 and 
this_.EstadoWorkflow in (SELECT this_0_.IdEstadoWorkflow as y0_ FROM EstadosWorkflows this_0_ WHERE this_0_.Final = 1) and 
exists (SELECT this_0_.IdPerfilPermiso as y0_ FROM Perfiles_Permisos this_0_ inner join Permisos prm1_ on this_0_.Permiso=prm1_.IdPermiso WHERE this_0_.IdPerfilPermiso in (206558, 206559, 209393, 209394) and (this_0_.PerfilAutorizado = prf2_.IdPerfil and this_0_.TipologiaAutorizada = this_.Tipologia and prm1_.Controlador = 'Incidencias' and prm1_.Accion = 'Index')) 
ORDER BY this_.Fecha desc
```

Execution time: **28506ms**.
Execution plan: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=72827687005228029776

**Query `NOT IN` with value `0`**

```
SELECT distinct top 15 this_.IdIncidencia as y0_, this_.Fecha as y1_ 
FROM Incidencias this_ inner join Usuarios usuario1_ on this_.Usuario=usuario1_.IdUsuario inner join Usuarios_Perfiles perfiles5_ on usuario1_.IdUsuario=perfiles5_.Usuario and (perfiles5_.perfil in (select perfiles.idperfil from perfiles where perfiles.borrado = 0)) inner join Perfiles prf2_ on perfiles5_.Perfil=prf2_.IdPerfil 
WHERE 
this_.Instancia = 4 and 
this_.EstadoWorkflow not in (SELECT this_0_.IdEstadoWorkflow as y0_ FROM EstadosWorkflows this_0_ WHERE this_0_.Final = 0) and 
exists (SELECT this_0_.IdPerfilPermiso as y0_ FROM Perfiles_Permisos this_0_ inner join Permisos prm1_ on this_0_.Permiso=prm1_.IdPermiso WHERE this_0_.IdPerfilPermiso in (206558, 206559, 209393, 209394) and (this_0_.PerfilAutorizado = prf2_.IdPerfil and this_0_.TipologiaAutorizada = this_.Tipologia and prm1_.Controlador = 'Incidencias' and prm1_.Accion = 'Index')) 
ORDER BY this_.Fecha desc
```

Execution time: **498ms**.
Execution plan: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=35554889075362686964

**Query `NOT IN` with value `1`**

```
SELECT distinct top 15 this_.IdIncidencia as y0_, this_.Fecha as y1_ 
FROM Incidencias this_ inner join Usuarios usuario1_ on this_.Usuario=usuario1_.IdUsuario inner join Usuarios_Perfiles perfiles5_ on usuario1_.IdUsuario=perfiles5_.Usuario and (perfiles5_.perfil in (select perfiles.idperfil from perfiles where perfiles.borrado = 0)) inner join Perfiles prf2_ on perfiles5_.Perfil=prf2_.IdPerfil 
WHERE 
this_.Instancia = 4 and 
this_.EstadoWorkflow not in (SELECT this_0_.IdEstadoWorkflow as y0_ FROM EstadosWorkflows this_0_ WHERE this_0_.Final = 1) and 
exists (SELECT this_0_.IdPerfilPermiso as y0_ FROM Perfiles_Permisos this_0_ inner join Permisos prm1_ on this_0_.Permiso=prm1_.IdPermiso WHERE this_0_.IdPerfilPermiso in (206558, 206559, 209393, 209394) and (this_0_.PerfilAutorizado = prf2_.IdPerfil and this_0_.TipologiaAutorizada = this_.Tipologia and prm1_.Controlador = 'Incidencias' and prm1_.Accion = 'Index')) 
ORDER BY this_.Fecha desc
```

Execution time: **386ms**.
Execution plan: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=11500314236594795220

Comment: Could we take a look at the actual execution plans? My first guess is that the IdTable2 is indexed, since it is (probably) a primary key, and ValueField is not. You do not really feel the difference for ValueField = 0 because there are not so many rows with that value.

Comment: Effectively IdTable2 is indexed and ValueField is not. I still don't undertand why differs when i change the comparission value. I'll post the execution plans in a few minutes

Comment: It is because the where clause scans the indexed column (IdTable2) in one case and non-indexed in the other case. It is not the question of '=' or 'IN' but the column you use in the where clause.

Comment: I understand what you say, but isn't the same column checked in the two first queries? Both use the same subquerie but with different check value on the same column maybe I missing something on your comment?

Comment: Updated with execution plans

Answer (score 2):

The reason that causes the problem is that SQL Server can't know the exact values that will be returned for the in -statement when it's being optimized, so statistics can't be used.

When you have the exact values in the in clause, they can be compared to statistics and SQL Server has most likely quite accurate estimate of how many rows there will be, and can then choose the best plan for the execution.

I haven't tried this myself, but you could try to create a filtered statistics for id, separately for the value field 0 and 1, maybe that would improve the situation.

**Update**

From the latest pictures, it can be clearly seen that the estimates are way off, the number of rows is estimated to be 1, but it's actually 59851 after the nested loop:

[image]

And this wrong estimate seems to cause a huge number of table scans, because it was expected to be done only once:

[image]

Since that's a table scan and not a clustered index scan, it looks like that table has no clustered index, and no other index that could be used either. Could you do something about that? Don't know about the amount of data, but index for `borrado` with included or normal column `idperfil` might help. This is what happens also in the in value 0 plan, but since the number of rows is only 605, the 605 table scans aren't taking that much time, but when you do it almost 100x more, it starts to take time.

Looking at the not in -plan, then the structure of the search is completely different, most likely because the estimated number of rows is closer to what it actually is, and SQL Server uses this kind of plan:

[image]

So another solution might be to create a temporary table out of Usuarios_Perfiles (with the perfiles -limitation) could help, since it's only 1179 rows.

Without statistics IO output, it's not 100% sure where the time is spent, but looks a lot like it's caused by the table scan.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, that's the main problem with subqueries (al least in SQLServer). But I still don't understand why using the same subquerie in a `NOT IN` instead of an `IN` the execution time is low and using `IN` the time is high. Isn't the same problem of not knowing the returned rows offered by the subquerie?. Anyway I'll try to do what you suggest.

Comment: I would assume the answer is the default amount SQL Server will estimate that equal / non-equal in statement will fetch from the table. Estimated number of rows in the query plan quite likely gives a hint

Comment: If this is a stored procedure (or dynamic SQL + parameters with binding) for the valuefield, also parameter sniffing could be related to this.

Comment: I'm making the tests directly on SSMS with plain sql, so stored procedure, dynamic sql or else don't apply. I update the question with execution plans

Comment: I assumed the cases would have a different query plan. Is the first one really taking significantly longer? The statistics are way off, estimated number of rows is 1 and actual number of rows is 59827, but at least it's not doing 60k lookups. Since you have select *, other indexes aren't going to be good, in real case if you're only fetching few columns, an index for EstadoWorkflow and other fields as included columns might be able to be used in a merge join, which could be faster than the hash match.

Comment: It would also be interesting to see the query plan for the "not in" case

Comment: Update with `NOT IN` query plans. Yes, is taking longer, but it get really, really worse when things start getting complicated (like adding more clauses, using joins,.. ect...) I'll get you a real production example with this same problem in a more complex query. I'll update question with those query plan in a while.

Comment: Updated with real production queries. I realize that there are other operations that are costly like the `exists` clause, and `joins` can be problematic as well. But as you can see I only get really bad executions times with `IN` with comparision value of `1`. I add the execution times for each query too, hope this would helpfull, please, let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: @ccasado Sorry that it took this long, but I updated my answer with some of the key points I think are visible in the query plans